# Spring Data Neo4j @Properties annotation

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I'm trying to port my legacy code to the latest version of Spring Data Neo4j and unable to find the following annotation:

```
@Properties (org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Properties)
```

What should be used instead of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the `@CompositeProperty` annotation.
This will work with `Map<String/Enum, Object>`.

Here is the link to the documentation with some further information.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#custom.conversions.composite-properties